# Emacs/CC-Mode doesn't indent arguments to templated functions starting with a curly bracket

Tags: c++, emacs, cc-mode

Consider the following snippet of C++ code, indented using cc-mode in Emacs:

```
auto good1 = f(a,
               {1, 2});   // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 1 15))
auto bad1 = f<1>(a,
  {1, 2});                // ((inexpr-statement) (block-open 36))

auto good2 = f(a,
               b,         // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 68 82))
               {1, 2});   // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 68 82))
auto bad2 = f<1>(a,
                 b        // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 114 130))
  {1, 2});                // ((inexpr-statement) (block-open 114))

auto good3 = f(a,
               b,         // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 151 165))
               {1, 2},    // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 151 165))
               c);

auto bad3 = f<3>(a,
                 b,       // ((arglist-cont-nonempty 209 225))
  {1, 2},                 // ((inexpr-statement) (block-open 209))
                 c);
```

As you can see, the curly-bracket-arguments `{1, 2}` are not indented properly when occurring in a templated function call. This is due to them being wrongly labelled as `((inexpr-statement) (block-open X))` rather than `((arglist-cont-nonempty Y Z))` (the exact offsets may be different, I edited the comments after using `C-c C-s` to get the syntactic labels).

Does anybody know how one can fix this? I tried the newest version of CC-Mode (5.32.5) specifically downloaded from Sourceforge as well as the default versions coming with Debian and Ubuntu, but all of them get this wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @wilx Fair point, I’ve reposted there; maybe a hint in the description of the “emacs” tag would be possible?

Comment: Cf. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19070/cc-mode-doesnt-indent-arguments-to-templated-functions-starting-with-a-curly-br